# How to interpret REML fixed effects summary?

Tags: linear-regression

Stats beginner here so apologies in advance. I have a linear mixed model fit by REML and I am trying to interpret the summary, in particular the estimates for the fixed and random effects.

The response variable is apple yield (yield), the fixed effects are year (2020 and 2023), variety (1, 2, and 3), flower count (initial flower numbers), variety by year, and flower count by variety. My random effect is tag number nested in variety.

To be honest I just want to know how to interpret these kinds of results in the future aka how to tell is there is an increase in yield for a particular variety between the years, or a difference in number of flowers between variety.

This is my model:

> model <- lmer(yield ~ Year + Variety + FlowerCount + Year:Variety + Variety:FlowerCount + (1+Variety|Tag.Number), data)

And I would like to understand the following summary results:

> ```
> > summary(model)                              
> Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']                                
> Formula: yield ~ Year + Variety + FlowerCount + Year:Variety + Variety:FlowerCount + (1 + Variety | Tag.Number)                               
>    Data: data                             
>
>
> REML criterion at convergence: 1752.5                     
>                       
> Scaled residuals:                         
>   Min 1Q  Median  3Q  Max 
>   -7.1024 -0.5209 -0.0567 0.5856  4.5072  
>                       
>
> Random effects:                       
>   Groups  Name    Variance    Std.Dev.    Corr    
>   Tag.Number  (Intercept) 0.3527  0.5938      
>       Variety2            0.3527  0.5938  -1  
>       Variety3            2.7906  1.6705  -0.8    0.8
>   Residual                8.0695  2.8407      
> Number of obs: 351, groups:  Tag.Number, 98                       
>
>
> Fixed effects:                        
>                   Estimate    Std. Error     df          t value  Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)           -1.94931    0.55661        121.79382    -3.502  0.000646    ***
> Year2023           3.46939    0.47561        301.92032    7.295   2.65E-12    ***
> Variety2           2.91781    0.75898        257.54062    3.844   0.000152    ***
> Variety3           2.97974    0.83893        153.57427    3.552   0.000508    ***
> FlowerCount            0.74791    0.02951        147.09705    25.342  < 2e-16         ***
> Year2023:Variety2 -4.00171    0.70468         288.6888    -5.679  3.31E-08    ***
> Year2023:Variety3 -4.51158    0.8374          304.5753    -5.388  1.43E-07    ***
> Variety2:FlowerCount  -0.57365    0.04849        315.35708    -11.831 < 2e-16         ***
> Variety3:FlowerCount   -0.4261    0.04422        246.80946    -9.635  < 2e-16         ***
> ---                       
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> ```